# Вывод результатов поиска в виде фрагмента текста с первым вхождением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, search

Искал в сети — ничего не нашёл подобного, окромя громадных функций для систем из коробки.

Суть такова: выводятся результаты в виде вырезанного куска текста в котором встречается первое совпадение (искомый термин). Например: «*Естественный ареал вида охватывает бассейны рек **Парана** и Парагвай. Культурное выращивание начато в XVII веке*...». Т. е. почти как в выдаче Google.

Вот некий код, который очевидно решает проблему, но я не знаю как прикрутить его к своей поделке:

```
$maxlength = 300; 
preg_match("/(^|\W).{0," . $maxlength/2 . "}$searchword{0," . $maxlength/2 . "}(\W|$)/i", $text, $matches);
```

У меня есть код, который подсвечивает искомый термин:

```
$row['text'] = preg_replace('/(' . $termin . ')/iu', '<span class="select_termin">$1</span>', $row['text']);
```

Пробовал сделать вот так:

```
preg_match("/(^|\W).{0," . 300/2 . "}$termin{0," . 300/2 . "}(\W|$)/i", $row, $row['text']);

echo $row['text'];
```

— выводит ошибку **Warning:** preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in **/site.org/search.php** on line **15** — ругается, что второй параметр массив, а не строка.

Как бы реализовать такую задачу, ну и сохранить подсветку из первого кода?

Comment: Ну и зачем вы передаете массив вместо строки?

Comment: Может пора прочесть описание функции и понять какой аргумент за что отвечает?

Comment: Прочтите ещё раз.

Comment: Что в `$row`? Что вы вообще хотите сделать?

Comment: Если  `row['text']` - строка, тогда `if (preg_match("/(?<!\w).{0," . 300/2 . "}" . preg_quote($termin, "/") . "{0," . 300/2 . "}(?!\w)/ui", $row['text'], $match)) { echo $match[0]; }` должно работать.

Comment: Я, кажется, пропустил точку. `preg_match("/(?<!\w).{0," . 300/2 . "}" . preg_quote($termin, "/") . ".{0," . 300/2 . "}(?!\w)/ui", $row['text'], $match)`

Comment: Да! Так лучше значительно. А как насчёт многоточий и выделения $termin? :))

Comment: Или лучше сделать чтобы выводилось просто предложение — от начала до точки, а количество знаков — сколько уж в предложении. Можно так?

Comment: Приведите пример строки и желаемый результат.

Comment: Пример строки: $row['text'] = '<p>По состоянию на 2011 год число описанных видов живых организмов составляло примерно 1,7 млн. Общее число видов, существующих на Земле, оценивается по-разному: называется число 8,7 млн, в том числе цветковые растения — около 400 тысяч видов (сейчас описано примерно 300 тысяч).</p>';

Comment: Искомое слово: $termin = 'видов';

Comment: Результат: $match = '<p>По состоянию на 2011 год число описанных <span style="color:red">видов</span> живых организмов составляло примерно 1,7 млн.</p>'; Нужно, чтобы из текста выдёргивалось предложение целиком, с первым совпадением. Но нужно учитывать, что предложение может быть как в начале, так и в середине и конце абзаца. И сам термин может быть в любой позиции (начале, внутри или конце).

Comment: Ваш вопос "слишком общий". Нужно разделить его на несколько: 1) как распарсить HTML в PHP (этого много в сети), 2) Разделить текст на предложения (надо искать среди NLP), 3) Поиск первого элемента списка, сожержащего совпадение целого слова 'видов'.